# Build Cordova 3.0.0 for Android

Tags: android, cordova

I have developed a PhoneGap application on IOS platform and try to build for Android but not succeeded.
It is giving error for Connection.

Cordova version: 3.0.0

Comment: could you please show proper error what you show in terminal

Comment: Please post logcat error.

Comment: Here is logcat: Uncaught ReferenceError: Connection is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/base.js:362